# Get Isotope Data and Electron Mass in Same Units - kg and Kilograms

Tags: physics, curated-data, units, chemistry

I'm trying to find the nuclear mass of $^{238}\text{U}$. To do this, I subtract the electron mass from the atomic mass. I'd like to find the final answer in kilograms. I'd also like to use *Mathematica*'s fancy built-in functions to do so.

The problem is that, when I do so, the units don't match.

```
U238Mass = Convert[IsotopeData["Uranium238", "AtomicMass"] AMU, Kilogram]
electronMass = UnitConvert[Quantity["ElectronMass"]]

(* Out: 
3.95293*10^-25 Kilogram
Quantity[9.109383*10^-31, "Kilograms"]
*)


U238Mass - electronMass

(* Out: 3.95293*10^-25 Kilogram + Quantity[-9.109383*10^-31, "Kilograms"] *)
```

The atomic mass is in Kilograms, but the electron mass is in kg (for some reason it shows up in the copy-paste as "Kilograms".

Any ideas on how to get both of these matching up?

Comment: Are you using some extra package? `Convert` is not currently a built-in function in *Mathematica* (v10.3). Perhaps you meant: `UnitConvert[IsotopeData["Uranium238", "AtomicMass"], "Kilograms"]`. From the physical standpoint, why would subtracting the mass of *one* electron give you the mass of the nucleus? A neutral uranium atom contains 92 electrons. Also, the mass of an electron is so small when compared to that of a baryon that even 92 of them only account for a fraction of a percentage of the mass of an U nucleus.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.  My top line is:

<< Units`

And yes, it should be 92 e-

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you running? Newer versions have the `Units` functionality built-in.

Comment: Version 9.0.1

I haven't been a mathematica user for long - can you comment on the distinction?  There appears to have been some sort of revamp of the units system or something like this?

Comment: Functionality from the `Units` package has been built-in to the main system since v.9 actually (see the [documentation for `Units`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Units/tutorial/Units.html)), so you should be able to use the built-ins. See my answer below as well.

Comment: I think where the confusing was arising was the an electron mass is, in itself, a unit, where the isotope data gives me the value of the isotope's mass in terms of AMU, another unit.

Answer (score 4):

You should try the following after restarting Mathematica to make sure that you don't run into conflicts with the `Units` package you had loaded.

```
U238Mass = UnitConvert[IsotopeData["Uranium238", "AtomicMass"], "Kilograms"]
electronMass = UnitConvert[Quantity["ElectronMass"], "Kilograms"]

U238Mass - 92 electronMass

(* Out:
Quantity[3.952926*10^-25, "Kilograms"]
Quantity[9.109383*10^-31, "Kilograms"]
Quantity[3.952088*10^-25, "Kilograms"]
*)
```

Alternatively, you can let the system deal with some conversions, and only convert at the end to the unit you desire for your answer:

```
UnitConvert[
 IsotopeData["Uranium238", "AtomicMass"] - 92 Quantity["ElectronMass"], 
 "Kilograms"
]
(* Out: Quantity[3.95209*10^-25, "Kilograms"] *)
```

You will notice that the contributions of the electrons to the mass of the atom is very very small.

Comment: I did this, but it didn't like the input.  I copied and pasted the line.
http://imgur.com/mp7IaVu

What's the difference between having the units in quotes and not in quotes?

Comment: Okay, I get it, the arguement should have been UnitConvert[Quanity[IsotopeData[....

Not ust UnitCovert[Isotopdat[....

Comment: @TerryPrice Perhaps this may be a limitation of your current version. Here is what I get when I run the code I posted:[results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M8BKM.png). Have you tried to restart the kernel, if you haven't already?

Comment: @TerryPrice - you are right, in version 9 `IsotopeData` does not return quantities.